# removing similar element from the array from sum of any two integer

Tags: java

My input is one integer suppose `M` and the program must print all the combination of two integer `x` and `y` where `x + y = M`.

Let us take our input as `M = 50` and array element as `25 20 25 30 15 45 45 5`
and my required output is

```
5 45,20 30,25 25.
```

But my output is coming as

```
5 45,5 45,20 30,25,25
```

How to remove the occurrence of that two times `5 45`?

My code is as follows

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int m = s.nextInt();
s.nextLine();
String str = s.nextLine();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);
int len = st.countTokens();
int[] a = new int[len];
String[] temp = new String[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    temp[i] = st.nextToken();
    a[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
}
Arrays.sort(a);

for (int i = 0;i < len-1; i++)
{
    for(int j = i + 1; j < len; j++)
    {
        if ((a[i] +a [j]) == m)
            System.out.println(a[i] + " " + a[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output for the input *M=50, arr={ 25 20 25 30 15 45 45 5 25  }*?

Comment: And what is the expected output for *M=50, arr={ 5 5 45 45 45 }*?

Comment: 5 45  20 30 25 25 is the expected output

Comment: @dbl 5 45 is the output which we want but we are getting 6 times that 5 45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `break` for skipping repeated number(inner loop) and check `(a[i] - a[i+1]) == 0` and use `continue` to skip repeated number in outer loop.

include only the following changes in the `for` loop, works perfectly

```
// Init a new array.
for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++)
{        
    if((a[i] - a[i+1]) == 0)
       continue;         // for skipping repeated number in outer loop 
    for(int j=i+1;j<len;j++)
    {
        if((a[i]+a[j])==m ) {
            System.out.println(a[i]+" "+a[j]);
            break;             // for skipping repeated number in inner loop
        }
      else if(a[i] == m/2){
        System.out.println(a[i]+" "+a[i]);
        break;
      }
    } 

}
```

**input**

```
25 ,20, 25 ,30, 15, 45, 45, 5
```

**output**

```
5 45
20 30
25 25
```

**input**

```
5 ,5 ,45, 45, 45
```

**output**

```
5 45
```

Comment: This approach will do the work but still it's a nasty one. It's more like a hack than a solution. Also just imagine if someone has to maintain this later on...

Comment: if my m=50,&array is  5 5 45 45 45 above logic is getted failed for this test case. it was printing 2 time 5 45.But we want only one time 5 45.

Comment: @RAVIKUMARSHARMACSE16, i updated you can check it and it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

(5 45) is printed two times as 45 occured 2 times in your input (25 20 25 30 15 **45 45** 5), if you need distinct pairs remove duplicates from array.

anyway this is not the best optimized solution. for more details check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-pairs-with-given-sum/

Comment: if i will remove the duplicate then i will not get the output single time also.actually i want it to give single time and the next time i dont want that output

Comment: remove duplicate I mean remove 45 second occurence, just keep it once.

Comment: This isn't a good approach. The problem I see here is that by removing the duplicates then you will not have the (25 25) pair in the output. Also if you allow duplicates over the (M/2 = 25) value than this could lead to printing this very same pair more than once.

Comment: break the inner loop once you found a match. cause after that if you find a match again it will be duplicate value only as other number is invariant.

Answer (score 0):

When just printing the correct pairs, you cannot check for the former solutions. You can add a[i] and a[j] whose sum is M to an array. After that, if a new pair summary gives M, you can check the array if elements in it.

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
int m=s.nextInt();
s.nextLine();
String str=s.nextLine();
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(str);
int len=st.countTokens();
int a[]=new int[len];
String []temp=new String[len];
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    temp[i]=st.nextToken();
    a[i]=Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
}
    Arrays.sort(a);

// Init a new array.
for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1;j<len;j++)
    {
        if((a[i]+a[j])==m) {
            // if(new array contains a[i]) continue;
            //array.add(a[i]);
            //array.add(a[j]);
            System.out.println(a[i]+" "+a[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to store in a list what you printed and not repeat a print if already printed.

```
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    int m=s.nextInt();
    s.nextLine();
    String str=s.nextLine();
    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(str);
    int len=st.countTokens();
    int a[]=new int[len];
    String []temp=new String[len];
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        temp[i]=st.nextToken();
        a[i]=Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
    }
    Arrays.sort(a);
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<len;j++)
        {
            if((a[i]+a[j])==m) {
                String msg = a[i]+" "+a[j];
                if(!output.contains(msg)) {
                    System.out.println(msg);
                    output.add(msg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    s.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to reinvent the wheel. Just put every pair in a `java.util.Set` so you only have distinct pairs:

Add this right before your last nested loop:

```
Set<String> pairs = new HashSet<>();
```

And change `System.out.println(a[i] + " " + a[j]);` to `pairs.add(a[i] + " " + a[j]);`

And in the end you can print the contents of the Set.

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##bZLLboMwEEX3fMWoK9MoFkmbVR5Sd63UrtJdxMINTmoCBtkmbVrx7XRs44S0FYiH72Hu3DE5O7Jxnh26TpR1pQzkuEAbIwp6O4@ibcG0hhcm5HcEUDdvhdiCNszg7ViJDEqUyNooIfebFJja69iSAOstk5Ir0LAEyT/CO1mftOElFTKeO05IAyUymkr@aZ6kIb3gF56F5GHF26C9OvN/5dfqwKX4ss4mWF8LBAsMzAsubTlDt1UjjaM0ueg2VV/HviGdDu1Qxjj1ldMA2lUKiHURSCRzvC2sIT6MRrEj/LTAVdmI1Ldio7lOQiMAzIs4IL7nitZMaW6n1X/Xc627PijFTppq3E/CesX3zM3C97iCmgkVNueR6XerrYLfr777tseTfxpH1JE5kgJGgEweUuYBvuA41B0Q4uKMMFWexrBcQhmfdfCtUZZlAbvBo4fDPNpBXp/N/1hVY2iNCU0hiavjvmijtutmSTSdwTQBvN4lMJnBvTtnPw)